# How to preserve a gel medium transferred photo image for long on the stone outdoors?

Tags: outdoor, print-preservation

I am trying to transfer some photos onto a slippery marble stone, 
  using some image transfer mediums  for outdoor landscape.

After transferring,  how can I preserve them outside as long as I want ?.

Comment: What is the image transfer medium you are using? How long is "as long as I want"? What environment will this be in? What conditions will the image be exposed to?

Answer (score 1):

"Transfer" Do you mean print in some material and then stick this into the wall?

You need to ask your provider about the materials and duration of the inks.
The magenta ink does not last as much as the cyan for example.

Normally for exterior you have a UV coating that gives you aditional protection against the sun, but this prints do not last as long as you want.

The specific duration depends on the material, the inks, the coating, the weather conditions, the orientation of the wall, interaction with people.

My recomendation is that you ask some providers and check the quality ot their prints. Do not make a "home made" aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an "Art store" may have some kind of spray matte or gloss aerosol varnish? Look for "[Plasti kote](http://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=plasti+kote)" ...looks ideal!

Comment: Look on Amazon for "Plasti kote" ...looks ideal!

Comment: Is there a particular Plastikote product you'd recommend? They make a whole lot of different things.